# Order by One Custom Field Value and Select Posts From Another With Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to only show posts that are marked as `in-stock` and order them by their `inventory_number` (which is a number value so I'm using `meta_value_num`). The code below is selecting `in-stock` items, but it isn't ordering the posts by `inventory_number`. What am I doing wrong?

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'post_status'=>"publish",
    'post_type'=>"post",
    'category_name'=>"tape",
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'inventory_number',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'asc'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'status',
                'value' => 'in-stock',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For order by on a custom field, `meta_key=keyname` must be present in the query. Plus I don't think you want the order by in the `AND` clause. So try this...

```php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'tape',  
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'status',
            'value' => 'in-stock',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'inventory_number',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it.